# Filename prefix test always failing in bash

Tags: bash

i have a question about using shell to read files. That is to say, i have a folder like this:

folder

- new_file.log  (this is a file)
- new_file2.log (this is a file)
- new_file3.log (this is a file)
- new   (this is a subfolder)

  - new_file_from_subfolder.log
  - new_file2_from_subfolder.log
  - new_file3_from_subfolder.log

what i want is to read all the content from (direct) files, not files from the subfolder. In the above case, i need new_file.log to new_file3.log.

I know there is a simple way:

```
 $ cat new*.log
```

but i also like to write a bash script:

```
for file in $(ls -a)
do  
    if [[ "$file" != "." && "$file" != ".." ]]; then            
        if [[ -f "$file" && "$file" == "^new" ]]; then  **here is the problem**
            [do something]
        fi  
    fi  
done
```

my problem is labeled as above.  the bash code seems doesnot like

```
 "$file" == ^new
```

if i run the bash, it basically does nothing, which means that files fail to meet the condition.
anything wrong?

Comment: Don't **EVER** use `ls` in scripts. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: ...if you want to make `for file in *` iterate over hidden files, `shopt -s dotglob` will have that effect.

Comment: ...also, it's not a particularly good habit to use `==` in shell except in a math context; POSIX specifies `=` as the non-numeric equality operator to `test`; shells supporting `==` do so as a non-standards-mandated extension. It's not as bad of practice in `[[ ]]`, since that's non-POSIX anyhow, but it's still easy for finger memory to translate the (safe) `[[ $foo == $bar ]]` into the (unsafe) `[ "$foo" == "$bar" ]` or `test "$foo" == "$bar"`, both of which need to be `=` to be portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[ $foo = $bar ]]` is a glob expression, not a regex; `^` has no special meaning there.

You probably want either the glob expression

```
[[ $file = new* ]]
```

or the regex

```
[[ $file =~ ^new ]]
```

---

Of course, in a real-world scenario, you'd just iterate only over the names that match your prefix:

```
for file in new*; do
  : something with "$file"
done
```

...or, recursively (using FD 3 so you can still interact with the user in this code):

```
while IFS= read -u 3 -r -d '' file; do
  : something with "$file"
done 3< <(find . -type f -name 'new*' -print0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're headed down the wrong track. Here's how to iterate over all regular files starting with `new`:

```
for file in new*
do
  if [[ -f $file ]]
  then
    dosomething "$file"
  fi
done
```